# Symfony2 get controller base route name

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get the Controller Class base route from within one of my methods. :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/buy-stuff", name="buy-stuff")
     * @Route("/sell-stuff" , name="for-sale")
     */
    class SalesController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="salesindex")
         * @Template()
         */
         public function indexAction()
         {  
            //Get the entry route here. eg: 'buy-stuff' or 'sell-stuff'     
         }


     }
```

I've tried:

```
$this->container->get('router')->getContext()
```

But there is nothing useful in there as far as I can see:

[Request Context](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/RequestContext.html)

Also, you can get a route if you know the name:

[Route Collection](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCollection.html)

But obviously, I don't in this instance.

Comment: please review my answer and ask if anything unclear so i can update it. otherwise accept the answer please :)

Comment: I solved it: From the Docs I found it:


    $this->container->get('request')->getPathInfo();

gives me 'buy-stuff' or 'sell-stuff' depending on my entry point


http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

Comment: This is just half of the story ... If you change one of your prefixes to /foo getPathInfo() will return foo and not the name (i.e. buy-stuff ) you associated with it and that was your original question :)

Comment: I want the route. So if I change the base route to 'foo', I want 'foo' in my indexAction()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) I found it:

```
$this->container->get('request')->getPathInfo();
```

gives me 'buy-stuff' or 'sell-stuff';

depending on my entry point.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$name = 'buy-stuff'; // controller action name
/** @var RouterInterface $router */
$router = $this->container->get('router');
$route = $router->getRouteCollection()->get($name);
$controllerAction = $route->getDefault('_controller');
// also you can get a lot of information from the $route variable
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "base route". The name definitions on these routes will have no effect.

```
 /**
  * @Route("/buy-stuff", name="buy-stuff")
  * @Route("/sell-stuff" , name="for-sale")
  */
 Class XY 
 {
     // ...
 }
```

You have a [Route Prefix](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix) configured in your Controller which does not have a name.

Get the current route name in a container-aware service / Controller with:

```
$route = $this->container->get('request')->get('_route');
```

The second option is the magic insertation of $_route in your controller.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function myAction($_route)
    {
        // ...
```

In Twig get your route like the following ( only works for master requests , not forwarded ones - use carefulyl with ESI )

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```

What you are trying to do can be accomplished by including a parameter in your route names and have two routing configurations each having a seperate prefix from a seperate container parameter.

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    acme.routep_refix.buy_stuff: /buy-stuff
    acme.route_prefix.for_sale:  /for-sale
```

Now create two routing configurations:

```
acme.buy_stuff:
    prefix:    %acme.route_prefix.buy_stuff%
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing_buy_stuff.yml"

acme.buy_stuff:
    prefix:    %acme.route_prefix.for_salef%
    resource: "@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing_for_sale.yml"
```

Comment: $route = $this->container->get('request')->get('_route');  gives me 'salesindex', as does $_route.

Comment: That is the correct behavior. There is no such thing as named route prefixes. It must be solved with parameters. Gimme a few minutes and i'll include an example :)

Comment: What I needed was: '$this->container->get('request')->getPathInfo();'

Comment: This may work for you and can be implemented as a solution but it is not the answer to your question. getPathInfo returns the path ( i.e. /for-sale ) not the route name as asked for in your question :)

Comment: Thanks for you help. I think the solution does answer my question. I didn't ask for the base route name, just the base route.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a special `$_route` variable, which is set to the name of the route that was matched.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param $_route
     */
    public function testAction($_route)
    {
        dump($_route);

        // Or by request_stack:
        dump($this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->attributes->get('_route'));

        // ...
    }

    // [...]
}
```

More info : https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#route-parameters-and-controller-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `$_route` in your action controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/stuff", name="stuff")
 */
class SalesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/buy", name="stuff_buy")
     * @Route("/sell" , name="stuff_sale")
     * @Template()
     */
     public function indexAction($_route)
     {  
        if ($_route === 'stuff_buy') {
            $something = '...';
        }
        if ($_route === 'stuff_sale') {
            $something = '...';
        }

        return array(
            'something' => $something,
        );
     }


 }
```